# Executed as user: dbo. You do not have permission to run 'SYS.TRACES'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8189)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

I am trying to run a simple trace select statement on SQL Server 2008 R2 it is failing.

It is failing when I try to invoke the below statement via a SQL Server Agent job, the service account of SQL Server Agent is part of Administrator group and has full SA access on server as well as on SQL Server Instance.

The same command when I run from query analyzer works fine, it is just driving me nuts where I am missing. And the good thing is the same select is running from SQL Server 2005 instance with no issues.

If anyone has face this issue please let me know..

Also the folder where the trace files are shared with full permissions.

```
SELECT top 1 SAT = id, SAF = [Path] 
FROM sys.traces 
WHERE [path] like 'C:\AuditTrace\SA%' 
ORDER by id
```

Error after running the above statement is via Sql Agent is

> Executed as user: dbo. You do not have permission to run 'SYS.TRACES'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8189). The step failed.

Forgot to mention that this particular statement is wrapped in a stored procedure which exists in another user database other than master.

Comment: The *Permissions* section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178579.aspx links to this fairly dense article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx which doesn't really have much to say about your problem. Apparently `sys.traces` is a replacement for `sys.fn_trace_getinfo` which "Requires ALTER TRACE permission on the server". The first article also says that `sys.traces` is deprecated.

Comment: Who is the owner of the SQL Agent Job?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
GRANT ALTER TRACE TO <user>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293611.aspx

Also, keep in mind that your user [permissions](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SOC4/Permissions?_ga=2.57462959.405928384.1600160872-274968949.1600160872) must be setup to allow you to do so.